# div onclick form not submitting in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form as follows:

```
<form action="saveorderdetails.php" id="submitForm" name="formsubmit" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="ordertabledetailshidid" name="ordertabledetailshid">
    <input type="hidden" id="datedetailshidid" name="datedetailshid">
    <input type="hidden" id="customerdetailshidid" name="customerdetailshid">
</form>
```

and I have a div as follows:
In that div I have a `onclick()` , which is used to submit the form.

```
<a href=""><div class="icon_boundary2" onclick="btn_save_click();"><i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:20px;padding:4px 0px 5px 5px; color:#7298CD;"></div></a>
```

My javascript function as follows:

```
function btn_save_click(){
    document.getElementById("submitForm").submit();
}
```

But the page is not getting submitted. Instead it is reloading. I have tried all the alternatives like:

```
document.getElementById("submitForm").submit();
```

But none of them working!!

Comment: Make it a `<button type="submit" form="formSubmit">`. No js needed

Comment: @AI.G I did not want that, I know form submit will work. I need it in this way!!

Comment: Remove `<a>` tag and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the anchor tag. This is how it should look like :

```
<div class="icon_boundary2" onclick="btn_save_click();"><i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:20px;padding:4px 0px 5px 5px; color:#7298CD;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it helped. But is there any way to do it with anchor tag also in it?

Comment: Why would you need an anchor tag with an empty href attribute?